# Custom Labels on Bar Chart Bars With Symbolic Coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

I want to put labels on the bars on this chart, but the labels I want are neither the x- nor y-coordinate of the bar, but some other text. It seems like I should be able to do this using `\node at (test\_1) {label}`, but I get an error when I try to compile this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Benchmark Speed Comparison of Cache Sizes},
    xlabel={Benchmark},
    ylabel={Benchmark Time [ns]},
    major x tick style=transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=6pt,
    x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
    symbolic x coords={test\_1, test\_2},
    ymax=500000000,
    xtick=data,
    ytick={100,1000,10000,100000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000},
    legend pos= outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ymode=log,
    log basis y={10},
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
]

\addplot[fill=red] coordinates { (test\_1,775) (test\_2,5597) };

\addplot[fill=blue] coordinates { (test\_1,112) (test\_2,112) };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Rendered chart]

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if I understand what you want to do. With

```
nodes near coords,
point meta=explicit symbolic
```

it is possible to set explizit labels for several bars

```
\addplot[fill=red] coordinates { 
  (test\_1,775)[\textcolor{red}{label}]
  (test\_2,5597)
};
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Benchmark Speed Comparison of Cache Sizes},
    xlabel={Benchmark},
    ylabel={Benchmark Time [ns]},
    major x tick style=transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=6pt,
    x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
    symbolic x coords={test\_1, test\_2},
    ymax=500000000,
    xtick=data,
    ytick={100,1000,10000,100000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000},
    legend pos= outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ymode=log,
    log basis y={10},
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    nodes near coords,
    point meta=explicit symbolic
]

\addplot[fill=red] coordinates { 
  (test\_1,775)[\textcolor{red}{label}]
  (test\_2,5597)
};

\addplot[fill=blue] coordinates {
  (test\_1,112)
  (test\_2,112)[\Large\textcolor{blue}{$\star$}]
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

If you want to set the labels manually do not use a backslash inside the symbolic coords. Use instead

```
symbolic x coords={test_1, test_2},
xticklabels={test\_1,test\_2},
```

and

```
\addplot[fill=red] coordinates { (test_1,775) (test_2,5597) };
\addplot[fill=blue] coordinates { (test_1,112) (test_2,112) };
```

Then it is possible to set an own label at the symbolic x coordinate `test_1`:

```
\node at (axis cs:test_1,2000){\textcolor{red}{label}};
```

Note that you have to use `axis cs:`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=15cm,compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Benchmark Speed Comparison of Cache Sizes},
    xlabel={Benchmark},
    ylabel={Benchmark Time [ns]},
    major x tick style=transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=6pt,
    x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east},
    symbolic x coords={test_1, test_2},
    xticklabels={test\_1,test\_2},
    ymax=500000000,
    xtick=data,
    ytick={100,1000,10000,100000,100000,1000000,10000000,100000000},
    legend pos= outer north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
    ymode=log,
    log basis y={10},
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
]

\addplot[fill=red] coordinates { (test_1,775) (test_2,5597) };
\addplot[fill=blue] coordinates { (test_1,112) (test_2,112)};

\node at (axis cs:test_1,2000){\textcolor{red}{label}};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```